# How to include ordered products in email using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, smtp

I have a online shop that collects data and displays the product and price on the page. The customer then needs complete the form and mail delivery address to me. Everything is working fine, but i would like to include the product that have been ordered in the email that comes to me.

My view_cart.php looks like this

```
    <?php
        $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
        {
            $total = 0;
            echo '<form method="post" action="paypal-express-checkout/process.php">';
            echo '<ul>';
            $cart_items = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
            {
               $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
               $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
               $obj = $results->fetch_object();
               $ShippinCost         = 150.00;

                echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
                echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
                echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj->price.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="product-info">';
                echo '<h3>'.$obj->product_name.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
                echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</li>';
                $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
                $total = ($total + $subtotal + $ShippinCost);
                if ($subtotal > 1200) { $total = $subtotal;
    }

                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
                $cart_items ++;
                echo 'Order Number:';
                $today = date("Ymd");
                $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
                echo $unique = $today . $rand;



            }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
            echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong>  ';
            echo '</span>';
            echo '</form>';

        }else{
            echo 'Your Cart is empty';
        }

        ?>

Then I have a simple HTML form that collects the info and sends it with ajax. This looks like this

<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

  ini_set("SMTP", 'smtp.xxxxxxx');
  ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
  ini_set('sendmail_from','noreply@domain.com');
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "sean@domain.co.za";"CC: info@domain.co.za "; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    $from_email     = "noreply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }

    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        # Mail headers should work with most clients
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $obj."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $product_code."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $cart_itm."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $total."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
        $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
        $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
    }else{
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

I have searched the site but cant find my solution. Please can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Given that there is an id to that order, i would look it up and look at the list of products associated with that, you might need to do a join, as there might only be a purchase_id and a list of Product ids, depending on how the system is created.

Comment: View_cart.php already fetches that for me. What I need to do is to add $obj $product_code $cart_item and $total to the email. I cant just add the to the email body as it would not know where to fetch this info so I need to know how to do that?

Comment: Ahh. didnt read your entire thing.   It sounds like a scope issue.  You will need to, before the message, refetch that information.  Apparently it is in the code, but its not there because it is out side the scope.  Id just refetch it, or store it as a cookie the first time.   I usually do that, when dealing with PHP.  I would store a list of data related to the product, so i can then fetch it easier later in the same session. Just make sure it isnt secure info, etc

Comment: That is what I have done, but it does not fetch that info. Somehow I need to tell contact.php to fetch that from view_cart.php - that is the bridge I do not know how to cross. Thanks for your help here

Comment: if both pages are in the same session, storing in COOKIE or SESSION might be sufficient

Comment: Could you point me to some place that will show me how to do this. I do not know how

Comment: //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ; 

So I need to add $obj, $product_code, $cart_item and $total to the piece above.

Comment: You are looking for:  $obj->product_name, $obj->product_code, $obj->product_description if i am not mistaken.  why dont you try it?  What does it say?  Are the the values of said objects?